# Gnu-Make fails to include a makefile

Tags: c, shell, makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html#Include):***

> The `include` directive tells `make` to suspend reading the current
>   makefile and read one or more other makefiles before continuing.  The
>   directive is a line in the makefile that looks like this:
>
> ```
>  include FILENAMES...
> ```
>
> ***FILENAMES can contain shell file name patterns.***

---

***Now, given a Makefile:***

```make
# we define 'include' from the command-line.
ifdef include


# We create the included Makefile
$(shell echo 'all : ;' >makefile.include)

# And we include it.
# The docs say: "FILENAMES can contain shell file name patterns."
include *.include


else


endif
```

***Running, we get:***

```console
$ rm -rf makefile.include && make include=1
makefile:6: *.include: No such file or directory
```

So, what happened here? We clearly had:

- Created a Makefile to be included, in:

  ```
  $(shell echo 'all : ;' >makefile.include)
  ```
- And later included this makefile, given that we can using "shell file name patterns", as quoted above from the documentation - and thus, we have in the makefile:

  ```
  include *.include
  ```

So, why did Gnu-Make failed to find this newly-created makefile?

Comment: Funny, this works fine if the Makefile is **explicitly** given -- `make -f testme.mk include=1` -- but not if it's just called `Makefile` and called as `make include=1`...

Comment: Is your included makefile really that simple? If so then there's a much easier way to do this.

Comment: This post is being discussed on meta. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306582/user-keeps-coming-back-with-new-accounts-asking-dishonest-non-questions

Answer (score 6):

The problem you are facing is not of inclusion, but of order of execution.

`make` is not a procedural language, but instead a *declarative* one, so order-of-execution sometimes gets a bit tricky.

In your specific case, `make` will parse the entire Makefile in the first pass, including the `include` statements, resulting in an erroneous Makefile, since there is no `makefile.include` yet.

It will *then* execute the `shell` command to create the `makefile.include` (but again it is too late: inclusion would have happened before).

A second run of `make` will then correctly include the `makefile.include`.

### Note:

The same is true for both directly using `include *.include` and `include $(wildcard *.include)` but only the former will result in an error (since the latter will expand the `*.include` to an empty set which will then (not) be included, whereas the former will try to include the literal `*.include` - similar to a stray `cat *.nonexistent` on the shell).

Comment: The docs say: "FILENAMES can contain shell file name patterns."

Comment: This is only ***generally*** true. But since version 3.81, Gnu-Make has a special exception for `include`, where it ***automatically*** expands any glob (pattern) characters. And this is precisely what I quoted from the docs, above.

Comment: true; re-evaluated the problem and changed the answer.

Comment: This is still not true. As Make clearly evaluated the `include` directive ***only after*** it created the Makefile (in the shell function). Try to change to `include makefile.include`, for example.

Comment: because `*.include` was evaluated before `shell`?

Comment: @umläute You can try to change to `include /tmp/*.include` and change accordingly the shell function to create the file `/tmp/makeifle.include`. Suddenly Gnu-Make finds the Makefile. Try yourself different variations of the above makefile, and see that we have here a ***Russian roulette.***

Comment: @umläute And the ***very good catch*** of [DevSolar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691355/gnu-make-fails-to-include-a-makefile#comment53226605_32691355) is the best example why your answer is not true. It clearly illustrates that `*.include` is only evaluated ***after*** the shell-function finished its respective fork.

Comment: i guess the order simply cannot be defined in the *declarative* part of the Makefile - which gives you undefined behaviour; so try not including wildcard files that are generated on the fly in the first place...

Comment: @umläute: If the order of the declarative part were not well defined, we'd be in deep trouble, because `SOURCES:=$(wildcard *.cpp)` followed by `OBJECTS:=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES))` would break half of the time...

Comment: @DevSolar there's a dependency between `OBJECTS` and `SOURCES`, whereas there is none between `include *.includes` and `$(shell ./somerandomscript.sh)`